# MongoDB[4.2] $text search not returning expected results

Tags: mongodb

We have author collection which contains author information for all the authors. We created text index using following

```js
db.getCollection('contributors').createIndex(
  {
    display_name:"text",
    first_name: "text",
    last_name: "text"      
  },
  {
     weights: {
       display_name: 10,
       first_name: 5,
       last_name:5
     },      
    name: "Contributor_FTS_Index"
  }
)
```

Here is sample data we have

```js
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5eac8232eb5aca201f104bfb"),
    "firebrand_id" : 54529588,
    "agents" : null,
    "created" : ISODate("2020-05-01T20:10:26.762Z"),
    "display_name" : "Grace Octavia",
    "email" : null,
    "estates" : null,
    "first_name" : "Grace",
    "item_type" : "Contributor",
    "last_name" : "Octavia",
    "phone" : null,
    "role" : 1,
    "short_bio" : "GRACE OCTAVIA is the author of unforgettable novels that deal with the trials and tribulations of love, friendship, and what it means to be true to yourself. Her second novel, His First Wife, graced the Essence® bestseller list and also won the Best African-American Fiction Award from RT Book Reviews. A native of Westbury, NY, she now resides in Atlanta, GA, where there is never any shortage of material on heartache and scandal. Grace earned a doctorate in English, Creative Writing at Georgia State University in Atlanta and currently teaches at Spelman College. Visit her online at GraceOctavia.net or follow her on Twitter @GraceOctavia2.",
    "slug" : "grace-octavia",
    "updated" : ISODate("2020-08-05T10:10:27.691Z"),
    "deleted" : false
}

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ada44aa2ad4b3e3d0ae3daf"),
    "item_type" : "Contributor",
    "role" : 1,
    "short_bio" : "",
    "firebrand_id" : 41529135,
    "display_name" : "Grace  Octavia",
    "first_name" : "Grace",
    "last_name" : "Octavia",
    "slug" : "grace-octavia",
    "updated" : ISODate("2020-09-22T16:19:57.319Z"),
    "agents" : null,
    "estates" : null,
    "deleted" : false,
    "email" : null,
    "phone" : null
}


{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58e6ee27afbe421347a11834"),
    "item_type" : "Contributor",
    "role" : 1,
    "short_bio" : "Octavia E. Butler (1947–2006) was a bestselling and award-winning author, considered one of the best science fiction writers of her generation. She received both the Hugo and Nebula awards, and in 1995 became the first author of science fiction to receive a MacArthur Fellowship. She was also awarded the prestigious PEN Lifetime Achievement Award in 2000. Her first novel, <i>Patternmaster</i> (1976), was praised both for its imaginative vision and for Butler’s powerful prose, and spawned four prequels, beginning with <i>Mind of My Mind</i> (1977) and finishing with <i>Clay’s Ark</i> (1984).<br /><br /> Although the Patternist series established Butler among the science fiction elite, it was <i>Kindred</i> (1979), a story of a black woman who travels back in time to the antebellum South, that brought her mainstream success. In 1985, Butler won Nebula and Hugo awards for the novella “Bloodchild,” and in 1987 she published <i>Dawn</i>, the first novel of the Xenogenesis trilogy, about a race of aliens who visit earth to save humanity from itself. <i>Fledgling</i> (2005) was Butler’s final novel. She died at her home in 2006.",
    "firebrand_id" : 11532005,
    "display_name" : "Octavia E. Butler",
    "first_name" : "Octavia",
    "last_name" : "Butler",
    "slug" : "octavia-e-butler",
    "updated" : ISODate("2020-09-23T04:06:18.857Z"),
    "image" : "https://s3.amazonaws.com/orim-book-contributors/11532005-book-contributor.jpg",
    "agents" : [ 
        {
            "name" : "Heifetz, Merrilee",
            "primaryemail" : "mheifetz@writershouse.com",
            "primaryphone" : "212-685-2605"
        }
    ],
    "estates" : [ 
        {
            "name" : "Estate of Octavia E. Butler",
            "primaryemail" : "",
            "primaryphone" : ""
        }
    ],
    "deleted" : false,
    "email" : null,
    "phone" : null
}
```

When we try to execute something like following;

```
db.getCollection('contributors').find({ $text: { $search: "oct" }})
```

it don't return any document. But if search for

```
db.getCollection('contributors').find({ $text: { $search: "octavia" }})
```

it returns all the document.

Our requirement is to give search result based on search term user entering. So it can be oc, oct, octav

Answer (score 0):

You picked the wrong tool. Text search in mongo uses whole words. Read more about mongo tokenizer at https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-text/#tokenization-delimiters

The part-word index requires ngram tokenizer. It is available in full-featured text engines. E.g. based on Apache Lucene: ElasticSearch, Solr, Mongo Atlas, etc.

If your database is relatively small and weights are not essential, you can use regexp:

```
db.contributors.find({
  "$or": [
    {
      displayname: {
        $regex: "oct",
        $options: "i"
      }
    },
    {
      first_name: {
        $regex: "oct",
        $options: "i"
      }
    },
    {
      last_mname: {
        $regex: "oct",
        $options: "i"
      }
    }
  ]
})
```

Comment: we have around 50k records and it will grow further in future. Above option will certainly work but not sure about performance. Also, what's wrong in text index we created ? We use text indexes for other collection and it works absolutely fine but some how don't work with this collection

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the index, it just doesn't work the way you expect it to. Please read the docs I referred in the answer to learn what mongodb fulltext search implementation can do and what it cannot.  If you have a set up where autocompletion scenario works I would love to learn details. 50k documents is small enough to use regexp without killing the server.

Answer (score 0):

Populer way to use this type of search Instead of $text so try like This,

```
db.contributors.find({
  "$or": [
    {
      display_name: {
        $regex: "oct",
        $options: "i"
      }
    }
 // add more fields objects same as above 
]

});
```